# How to make Boto3 Silent Failures loud?

Tags: python, boto3

I have the following

```
print("A")
client = boto3.client("events")
print("B")
```

A is printed, but B is not. I suspected that boto3 was silently failing so I added the following

```
try:
    client = boto3.client("events")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

And it turned out that there was a "You must specify a region" error. Which is all fine and good, except that I feel like I shouldn't have to explicitly catch and print exceptions. I'd expect them to end up getting printed automatically along with a nice stack trace when my application crashes.

Is there any way to get that behavior out of boto3?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is specific to boto3? Based on what you've described so far I think error handling is [configured in a non-standard way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook), and it's probably going to happen on other kinds of exceptions, too.

Comment: There is no such thing as a silent failure unless your top level environment catches and ignores the error but boto cannot do anything about that, only your surrounding environment can. And by default no environment should just ignore errors, have never experienced that, that is very non-standard. The fact that you can actually catch the exception in the second snippet directly shows that this issue is not related to boto since boto obviously correctly throws an exception, as expected.

Comment: You make very good points. Interestingly though, I don't have any Except blocks anywhere else in my code that could be catching and burying exceptions.

Comment: You don't need an except block to bury an exception. See the link in my previous comment, or try `import sys;sys.excepthook = lambda type,value,traceback: None; raise RuntimeError`